# How would one implement multiple front end javascript frameworks in one project?

Tags: javascript

How would you divide their implementation for a website for example? Do you divide it between different features, pages, etc. or can you implement it in the same division?

Comment: @ZachPerkitny You may be confusing "libraries" with "frameworks".

Comment: What do you mean by "division"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing modular javascript and using a bundler like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). With both, you're able to tap into a world of NPM JavaScript packages. For custom project code, keep it modular `module.exports = function() {...}`. Organize code locally first by what is common/shared. Then by screen and then after that by component if it makes sense.

dir/
..shared/
....header/
....footer/
..screen/
....home/
......intro/
....about/
......jobs/

With Webpack, you can then use the code-splitting features to split up bundles in ways that make the most sense for browser caching & lazy-loading. All that said, I don't think there's a magical answer, right every time, for all apps. It's probably best to start with a strategy and be flexible. Change it based on how the app evolves and the efficiency with how the team works with it.